# VBA HTML clicking buttons in a web page

Tags: html, vba

I'm a newbie in programming, but I'm willing to learn some. I got this problem with using VBA to click buttons in a web page.

```
<input name="TheConditions" id="condition100" 
onclick="CExchange3.Views.ShowQuestionStars.updateCondition('100');" type="radio">
```

I have used this argument

```
objIE.Document.getElementById("condition100").Click
```

It doesn't seems to work for me. Does it have to show on the page that it has been clicked for it to work? I hope you can shed some light on this. Thanks.

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking.  what does this statement mean? _Does it have to show on the page_  ... are you seeing the webpage, but nothing happens when the code supposedly clicks the button? if you are seeing the web page, but nothing happens, then it is not working. ... try to click the button with the mouse, just to see if the button is clickable.

Comment: I would like to automate clicking of buttons on a webpage which has 6 radio buttons. When I run the program I have made the buttons are still unclicked on the loaded site. what argument should I use to properly click buttons.

Comment: Could you please post the code you are using, so that others be able to reproduce such behaviour. Also try `objIE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "CExchange3.Views.ShowQuestionStars.updateCondition('100');", "JScript"`.